# Ошибка в задаче, поиск клада

Tags: c++

Приветсвую, есть задача: дана карта (в виде двумернного массива). На карте есть 3 подсказки, сколько шагов по горизонтали и вертикали нужно сделать чтобы найти клад.

Решаю следующим, найти все возможные маршруты на карте. Места в массиве с цифрой 0, должный граничить с 3-мя 1.
Пример:
10123 |
01000

Клад находится в индексах [0][1] первая линейка, 2 столбец

Если таких мест больше чем 1, результат
cout << “Нехватает информации»;

Код отправляеться на сервер, проходит 4 теста из 5-ти, но в одном ошибается. Входных данных у меня нет, поэтому немогу понять где ошибка.

```
int main() {
    int n, m; // размер двумеррного массива n*m

    int contains = 0; // что содержит элемент массива

    cin >> n >> m;
    
    // **** Создать двумернный массив *****

    int** map = new int* [n];

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        map[i] = new int[m];
    }

    
    // *** Заполнить массив * *****

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> contains;
            map[i][j] = contains;
        }
    }

    // *** Заполнить все возможнные шаги

    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {

                    if (map[i][j] > 1) {
                    contains = map[i][j];

                    if (j > 0 && map[i][j - 1] < contains - 1)
                        map[i][j - 1] = contains - 1;
                    if (i > 0 && contains - 1 > map[i - 1][j])
                        map[i - 1][j] = contains - 1;

                    if (j < m && map[i][j + 1] < contains - 1)
                        map[i][j + 1] = contains - 1;

                    if (i < n && contains - 1 > map[i + 1][j])
                        map[i + 1][j] = contains - 1;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Подсчёт соседей
    
    int kaimyn_kiek = 0;
    int vietu = 0;
    int X_cords;
    int Y_cords;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            kaimyn_kiek = 0;
            if (map[i][j] == 0) {
                if (j > 0 && map[i][j - 1] == 1)
                    kaimyn_kiek++;
                if (i > 0 && map[i - 1][j] == 1)
                    kaimyn_kiek++;

                if (j < m && map[i][j + 1] == 1)
                    kaimyn_kiek++;
                
                if (i < n && map[i + 1][j] == 1)
                    kaimyn_kiek++;


                if (kaimyn_kiek >= 3) {
                    kaimyn_kiek = 0;
                    X_cords = i + 1;
                    Y_cords = j + 1;
                    vietu++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    // ** Результат
    if (vietu == 1)
        cout << X_cords << " " << Y_cords;
    else
        cout << "Нехватает информации";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как минимум `i <= n` в условии цикла где выделяется память может всё поломать

Comment: Достаточно координат двух точек и расстояний по этой координате, чтобы определить местоположение по этой координате. Обязательное условие - координаты должны различаться. И никаких маршрутов искать не надо. Недостаточность данных - это когда все три точки лежат на одной вертикали либо горизонтали.

Answer (score 1):

Так у тебя в самом начале ошибка.

```
int** map = new int* [n]; // n - Это размер всего массива (1, 228 и т.д)
// for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) -- '<=' Так НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО!
/* 
   Вот тут ты написал <=, но отсчёт начинается от 0 и до конца массива, 
   т.е в твоём случае номер последнего элемента будет (n - 1). 
   
   Используя '<=' в данной ситуации ты выходишь за рамки массива, 
   это не есть хорошо!

   Это легко запомнить, т.к. массив сам по себе это указатель 
   'pointer[offset]', где `pointer` - указатель, а offset - смещение.
   Говорив poiner[0] ты говоришь *(pointer + 0), а pointer[1] - 
   *(pointer + 1).
*/
for (int i{}; i < n; i++) // -- '<' Вот так правильно!
for (int i{}; i <= n - 1; i++) // Вот так тоже правильно, но зачем?
for (int i{ n - 1 }; i >= 0; i--) // Тоже самое, что и выше, только наоборот
```

---

ИМХО, лучше всего используй `std::vector`, лично мне кажется он в данной ситуации больше подходит. Посуди сам:

```
/* Вместо вот этого */
int n, m; 
int** map = new int* [n];

/* Вот это */
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecMap{};

/* Тем более безопасней */
/* Вместо */
for (int i{}; i < n; i++)
{
    // ...
}

/* Вот это */
for (auto &vec_map : vecMap)
{
    vec_map[0][2] = 1991;
    // ...
}
```

Подробнее про `std::vector` можешь прочитать вот тут - [vector - cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в алгоритме решения задачи, однако во многих циклах также был выход за пределы массива, что не есть хорошо.

Дело в том, что первый алгоритм ошибался, потому-что  возможный путь от одной точки считался как за два разных.
Как решил:

1. Сохраняем в двухмерный массив первичные данные.
2. Для каждой подсказки создаётся отдельный двухмерный массив, на котором просчитывается возможный маршрут. Первичный же массив заполняем нулями.
3. Конец маршрута для каждой подсказки отмечается в первичном массиве, место где 3 точки пересекаются и есть ответ, в случае если таких точек больше или нет, ответ: недостаточно данных.